# phantomjs не работает с https

Tags: phantomjs

Пробовал разные опции

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true
--web-security=false
--ssl-protocol=any
```

Всегда вылетают ошибки и только на определенном сайте. На других работает

```
2015-08-14T15:36:54 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 205 ( "Unknown error" )

2015-08-14T15:31:43 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 6 ( "SSL handshake failed" )
```

Ничего не погомает

В чем может быть проблема?

Проблема решилась. Оказалось что нужно было передавать дополнительно заголовки для Basic Auth )

Comment: Проблема может быть на определённом сайте. Он у вас в браузере открывается? Сертификаты там валидные?

Comment: Вполне вероятно что там просто нет https...

Comment: @IvanSolntsev Сайт открывается, chrome в сведениях о сайте говорит что сертификат подтвержден и все ок. Сам я в них не разбираюсь

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну как нету? Если данные о сайте о другом говорят

Comment: Для доступа нужна авторизация, может быть в этом проблема?

Comment: Вероятно на сайте отключены некоторые SSL протоколы, судя по тикету https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13496 у них есть проблемы с TLS

Comment: попробуйте добавить `--ssl-protocol=any`

Comment: @IvanSolntsev так же пробовал, но не помогло 

`Resource request error: 205 ( "Unknown error" )`

Comment: @JILeXanDR ну вот просто нету, а "данные о сайте" не соответствуют действительности. Браузер и/или wget натравите на ваш URL

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Дополнительно, нужно было передавать заголовки для Basic Auth.

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает с таким сочетанием опций, попробуйте.

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true server.js
```

Comment: ни одна опция не подошла... Оказалось что нужно было передавать дополнительно заголовки для Basic Auth )